# If the sides of a quadrilateral are $a,b,c,d$, prove that the area cannot exceed $(ac+bd)/2$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, area, quadrilateral

> MOP 1997: Let $Q$ be a quadrilateral whose side lengths are $a,b,c,d$ in that order. Show that the area of $Q$ does not exceed $(ac+bd)/2$.

My solution: Without loss of generality, let $a$ be the longest side. I first prove that the area cannot exceed (a**b**+c**d**)/2. Drawing a diagonal, we can divide the quadrilateral into two triangles with sides are $a$ and $b$, and $c$ and $d$. The triangle with sides $a$ and $b$ can have maximum area if the angle between them is $\pi/2$. In this case, the area between them will be $\frac{1}{2}ab$. Similarly, the area of the other triangle can have a maximum of $\frac{1}{2}cd$. Adding them up, we get that the maximum area of the quadrilateral can be $\frac{1}{2}(ab+cd)$.

Now if this maximum is achieved, which means that the angle between $a$ and $b$, and $c$ and $d$ are both $\pi/2$, **by drawing a diagram, we can convince ourselves that $a=c$**. This means that $a$ and $b$ are both the longest sides in the quadirlateral. Hence, by the rearrangement inequality, we have $(ab+cd)/2\leq (ac+bd)/2$. Hence, the area of the quadrilateral is less than or equal to $(ac+bd)/2$.

Is the reasoning given above correct? Does there exist a better proof?

Comment: What's the MOP? Did the question come from [here](http://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/dangeba/geom-080399.pdf)?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik- It did. It's the very first question in the book

Comment: You claim that '**by drawing a diagram, we can convince ourselves that $a=c$**'. Are you sure?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva- Not sure anymore. It seems I didn't consider the possibility of the angle between $b$ and $c$ being greater than $\pi/2$.

Comment: You're right when you claim that the area is maximized when the angle in between is $\pi/2$

Comment: The thing is, that I don't see $a=c$ as a direct consequence...

Answer (score 4):

Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be diagonals of the quadrilateral.

Thus, $$S=\frac{1}{2}d_1d_2\sin\measuredangle(d_1,d_2)\leq\frac{1}{2}d_1d_2$$ and by the Ptolemy
$$ac+bd\geq d_1d_2\geq2S.$$

Comment: For clarity, the [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_inequality), not the [equation for cyclic quadrilaterals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem).

Comment: @J.G. All these named the Ptolemy's theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Just to give you context, the place where I read the problem claims that there exists a diagrammatic solution. You may be able to just draw a diagram and prove it.

Comment: @Anju George For the convex quadrilateral there is a nice and easy diagrammatic  solution with two triangles. But in the general case my solution is a best, I think.

Comment: @J.G In which nomenclature you think that I am wrong? Explain please. I really don't understand you.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I don't think you're wrong. I just thought those hyperlinks would help some readers.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg "My solution is a best" It seems to me that it's not the first time that you comment in such a way your solutions. Take it with humor :) :) :)

Comment: @Jean Marie Yes, you are right! I know, it's not so good, to say this, but I really think so. Because for the concave quadrilateral $ABCD$ the idea with replacing $\Delta ABC$ on $\Delta CBA$ not always works.

Comment: I must say as well that I have learned a lot from your mastering of inequalities !

Answer (score 1):

**Alternatively** (and I know that this solution isn't diagrammatic):

As you claimed, the area of a triangle given two sides $a,b$ is maximized when $\gamma=90°$ since you can express the area of a triangle as $$A=\frac{a·b·\sin\gamma}{2}$$ and $\sin\gamma\leq1$ with equality if $\gamma=90°$. Thus the area of the quadrilateral, given the sides $a,b,c,d$ is maximized when this quadrilateral is cyclic. The [area $K$ of cyclic quadrilaterals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral) can be expressed as
$$K=\frac{1}{2}·(ac+bd)·\sin\theta\leq \frac{1}{2}·(ac+bd)·1$$